# Restrict users to use incorrect Subkey

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, subscriber-key

Is there a way to apply a restriction so users can only import ContactID as Subkey to a sendable DE?

The use case is our SFMC users have been using Member_ID (a 6 or 7 digit number) as Subkey for email sends but now we want them to use ContactID (Sales Cloud Contact ID) only. This is to prevent having two set of subkeys for au audience. This increases contact count and creates challenge for reporting. We have tried to encourage them but you always get someone 'forgot' about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restrict the manual import or add a validation layer when importing.

However, there is an option:

1. Let's say all your imports are going to target "Intermediate_Data_Extension" (you can specify that for all stakeholders) and then you can have a simple automation
2. Add SQL Query activity to the automation that will check the length of the received SubscriberKey - since you are saying that Member_ID = 6 or 7 digit number and CRM Contact ID is always 18 digits long, so you will have something like -

```
SELECT * FROM [Intermediate_Data_Extension]
WHERE LEN(SubscriberKey) = 18 AND SubscriberKey LIKE '003%'
```

Then you would always have only Contact ID  as a Subscriber Key in the main DE.

You can also go further and populate another DE that would hold only records where Member_ID is SubscriberKey and then with Verification activity check if it is not empty, then to get notification about that.

Comment: Nice solution, I would however extend it with RegEx, so you are sure the ID not only has the right length, but also the right type: ^003\w{15}$, like this: SELECT * from [IDE] where PATINDEX('^003\w{15}$', SubscriberKey) > 0

Comment: @LukasLunow yep, that is better and eliminates some data inconsistencies. Will update the answer, if you do not mind.

Comment: Thanks Niko and Lukas. My situation maybe a little more challenging as the stakeholders are very used to old process and they would find any excuses to not use the new method :(

Comment: @Eliott, as I said in the answer below, no available function exists at the moment. You would always only be able to check incoming data once it is imported already.

Comment: @LukasLunow, your `PATINDEX('^003\w{15}$', SubscriberKey) > 0` does not work unfortunately. I am not an expert with this syntax but it is easier to work with a similar approach of having - `LEN(SubscriberKey) = 18 AND SubscriberKey LIKE '003%'`